# Managing sphinx over heading and images

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to build small document site based on sphinx tool.

My exact requirement on the main landing page which is "index.rst" i need to bring two images on the top one is on the left hand side and other is on the right hand side.

As per below code, the image stands correctly, but the problem is that the heading string "Welcome page" falls between the two images space. Actually I would need to shift the heading down the image after some lines.

```
.. figure::  /images/logo1.png
   :align: left
   :scale: 30%

.. figure::  /images/logo2.png
   :align: right
   :scale: 30%



Welcome page
============
```

Please suggest

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Most people accept what sphinx and a default theme offer. If you want to fully customize individual elements (as this question shows), you need to dig further into the generated HTML and figure out where you can extend CSS styles to render the elements in the way you wanted. Unfortunately that's a huge topic and you might need to hire a consultant if you are not familiar with HTML/CSS. Impossible for anyone to answer via SO.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the suggestion. Let me have a look

Comment: The extension [`sphinx-design`](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is nice for doing layout things that are otherwise not easily supported in Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

I tested myself with raw:: html and worked for me. Below is the solution

```
.. raw:: html

    <h2><span class="section-number"> </span><a class="headerlink" href="" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h2>

.. rst-class:: center

Welcome page
============
```

On custom.css file, i need to define for the center alignment for the heading as follows

```
.center h1,
.center h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This fixed my requirement. Hence marking this as solved